# 127.0.0.1 is refusing to connect when I use import dash

Tags: python, css, flask, web, server

```
[Error while connecting to 127.0.0.1[\]\[1\][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo2mY.png
```

My code is like this :-
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

```
from pandas_datareader import data as web
from datetime import datetime as dt

app = dash.Dash('Hello World')

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='my-dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Coke', 'value': 'COKE'},
            {'label': 'Tesla', 'value': 'TSLA'},
            {'label': 'Apple', 'value': 'AAPL'}
        ],
        value='COKE'
    ),
    dcc.Graph(id='my-graph')
], style={'width': '500'})

@app.callback(Output('my-graph', 'figure'), [Input('my-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_graph(selected_dropdown_value):
    df = web.DataReader(
        selected_dropdown_value,
        'google',
        dt(2017, 1, 1),
        dt.now()
    )
    return {
        'data': [{
            'x': df.index,
            'y': df.Close
        }],
        'layout': {'margin': {'l': 40, 'r': 0, 't': 20, 'b': 30}}
    }

app.css.append_css({'external_url': 'https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='127.0.0.1',port = 8050,debug=True)
```

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------My question when I try to put http://127.0.0.1:8050  it says 127.0.0.1  refused to connect.Mine is windows 10 OS.I tried IIS services but still I dont know how to use that.Please help me with the error.

Thanks.